# Can we access class method variable using dot notation in python

Tags: python

Below is the code

```
import os

class ABC:
    def test(self,name):
        var = 5
        var2 = 10
        dic = {"Ada": "adada"}
        print "asdfdsadv"
        var1 = "Ada"
        var2 = "asada"

obj = ABC()
print obj.test("Ada").var1
```

I am looking for something like this. Can I achieve this in python

I know this is var variable in local to class. Is there someway by using global or something else to acheive this

Comment: you need have a return function and call it; you can't call directly a variable

Comment: That would be a poor design. I have a feeling you have an XY problem

Comment: I suggest you to have a look on classes from [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) official python docs

Comment: No, that is a local variable.

Comment: Why negative marking for this question. I failed to understand sometimes. Negative marking should be done when the question is not clear. I have seen the pattern people giving negative rating just because they dont know the answer.

Comment: @Nitesh I think their problem is more that they do not like what you are asking for because it is not the pythonic way. Its kind of a sect ;) check out this style guide https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/style/

Answer (score 2):

Accessing a variable from a class method is not possible, you have to set the variable at the class level like this:

```
import os

class ABC:
    def test(self,name):
        var = 5
        var2 = 10
        dic = {"Ada": "adada"}
        print "asdfdsadv"
        self.var1 = "Ada"
        var2 = "asada"

obj = ABC()
obj.test('Ada')
print obj.var1
```

You could chain obj.test('Ada').var1 in the same line by returning self into your test method.

Answer (score 2):

I think this would work. The **init**(self) behave like a constructor in other languages. So in effect I am constructing a class in a class, to make your last line work properly. But like other suggested that is not the way Python is supposed to be used.

```
import os

class ABC(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    class test(object):
        def __init__(self,name):
            self.var = 5
            self.var2 = 10
            self.dic = {"Ada": "adada"}
            print ("asdfdsadv")
            self.var1 = "Ada"
            self.var2 = "asada"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = ABC()
    print (obj.test("Ada").var1)
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for are the `class variables`, usually defined as `self.variable`. Here an example of your code:

```
import os

class ABC:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 5
        self.var2 = 10
        self.dic = {"Ada": "adada"}
        self.var1 = "Ada"
    def test(self,name):
        print self.var
        print self.var2
        print self.var1 + " " + name

obj = ABC()
print obj.dic # {'Ada': 'adada'}
print obj.dic["Ada"] # adada
obj.test("wow") # 5, 10, Ada wow
obj.var1 = "Ede"
obj.test("wow") # 5, 10, Ede wow
```

but as suggested in other answers, you may want to take a step back and check what is the [scope](https://matthew-brett.github.io/teaching/global_scope.html) of python variables

Comment: That wasn't what the OP asked. `print` does not return the attribute

Comment: I am not completely sure that the OP has the knowledge tu fully identify what he exactly need, so supposing an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) I gave the answer that I think will mostly help him. Plus, if you read the answer, you'll notice that the metod `.test` is here only as an example, meanwhile the part that *returns the attribute* is `obj.dic["Ada"]`; the rest is to provide a fast introduction to *class variables*

Answer (score 1):

Forget about classes and consider functions in general.

When you define a function, any variables within its scope are *local* and only accessible from within the execution of that function. Once execution has finished, that's it, they are gone. This is fundamental; the only way of getting data from a function is by `return`ing it.

---

Although it is a hack, you could return `locals()` (a dictionary of local variables), but this is terrible practice.

```
import os

class ABC:
    def test(self,name):
        var = 5
        var2 = 10
        dic = {"Ada": "adada"}
        print "asdfdsadv"
        var1 = "Ada"
        var2 = "asada"
        return locals()

obj = ABC()
print obj.test("Ada")["var1"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you return the object itself from the function and the variables are not local but instance variables it works.

```
class ABC:
    def test(self, name):
        self.var1 = "My name is {}".format(name)
        return self

obj = ABC()
print obj.test('Ada').var1
```